# One liner code challenge to generate sum

Tags: c#

I am trying to achieve the following:

```
x = 0 | Result = 23
x = 1 | Result = 34
x = 2 | Result = 45
x = 4 | Result = 56
```

I have tried a simple for loop for this:

```
int s = 23;
if (x == 0)
    return 23;
else
{
    for (int i = 0; i < t; i++)
    {
        s += 11;
    }
    return s;
}
```

But I have to write smart code so I wrote this:

```
return Enumerable.Range(0, x).Sum(m=>m= 11) + 23;
```

But I am still unable to get full marks, is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need a loop at all. Just calculate the value from `x`:

```
return 23 + x * 11;
```

Comment: maybe because I have been programming for 9 hours continuous